# Python Nuke - How to use variable result from another function

Tags: python, function, return, nuke

I have some trouble with the return of a function. I want to create a Nuke script that asks the user a directory and automatically set the path to this directory in a Write Node with the current date, hour, etc. This part was pretty easy (this is the `DateWrite()` function in the provided code)

Now, I want to open this directory after the render is finished. So I have to use Callbacks and call a function that opens the given directory.

This is where I get some trouble : since the directory is set in the first function, I tried to get the value of this function with a `return`.

It works, but it forces me to use the first function twice (this part is the `openDirectoryAfterRender()` function)

```
#Modules import
import nuke
import subprocess

# Create DateWrite function
def DateWrite():

    # Create Variables
    selectedNodes = nuke.selectedNodes() # Get Selection of all selected nodes

    if len(selectedNodes) == 1:
        filePath = nuke.getFilename('Set Output Directory') # Asks the user to set an OutPut directory for the Write Node

        writeNode = nuke.createNode("Write") # Create a Write Node
        writeNode['file'].setValue(filePath + "[file rootname [file tail [value root.name]]]_[date %y][date %m][date %d]_[date %H][date %M].png") # Set the Write Node with TCL
        writeNode['afterRender'].setValue('openDirectoryAfterRender()') # Add a callback which will call the function openDirectoryAfterRender()

    else:
        nuke.message("No node selected or more than one node are selected.\nPlease select only one node.")
    return filePath

# Create openDirectoryAfterRender
def openDirectoryAfterRender():
    directoryToOpen = DateWrite() # Get the returned directory from DateWrite() -but also execute DateWrite another time-
    directoryToOpen = directoryToOpen.replace('/','\\') # Replace the slashes with backslashes

    subprocess.Popen('explorer %s' % directoryToOpen) # Open the chosen directory
```

I am pretty new to Python and code in general, so this is probably a noob question.
I tried a lot of different solutions, this one is the closest I can get to from what I want.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: "it forces me to use the first function twice". Note that the line `def DateWrite():` is _defining_ the function, not calling it. As your code is now, you execute `DateWrite` exactly once. Or do you mean "it forces me to assign to `directoryToOpen` twice"? You could do it in one line with `directoryToOpen = DateWrite().replace('/', '\\')`.

Comment: The only downside to what @Kevin suggested is that if DateWrite retuns `None`, you'll get an Attribute error. If `len(selectedNodes) != 1` `DateWrite()` returns `None`.

Comment: I think right now if `len(selectedNodes) != 1`, then it will crash with an `UnboundLocalError` on the `return` since nothing got assigned to `filePath` at all.

Comment: `os.path` has a method called `normpath` which you might find more useful than `.replace( '/', '\\' )` depending on what platform you are on.

Comment: "As your code is now, you execute DateWrite exactly once."

Actually, `DateWrite` is executed twice, even if I execute just `openDirectoryAfterRender` : when execute the function, and when the render is finished. Even if I try `directoryToOpen = DateWrite().reaplce('/', '\\')` it execute the `DateWrite` function a second time (since there's `DateWrite()` in the variable `directoryToOpen`).

My main issue is that I don't want `DateWrite` to be executed when I declare my `openDirectoryToOpen` variable. I don't know if it's clear or not, and I might be wrong in the thinking process :)

Comment: @Kevin sorry I forgot to mention you in the above comment

@FluxIX thanks for this method, very useful !

@Pericolo I'll probably add a `nuke.message()` in the case where the user doesn't select any directory. `DateWrite` will still return `None` but at least the user won't be surprised. Thanks !

Comment: Ok, I think we're going to need a [mcve] here. `DateWrite` should only get called when you call `openDirectoryAfterRender`, and you never call that, so DateWrite should execute zero times. And what's that `nuke` module you're importing on the first line? I can't run this code on my machine at all without it.

Comment: @Kevin the `nuke` module is from the Nuke software, which is a compositing software (let's say it's Photoshop but for videos).

I want my script to automaticaly add a Write Node (a Nuke object) already set with the good output (the output is chosen by the user). This part is the `DateWrite` function and it does works well.

Then, the user have to click on Render (in the Write Node created by `DateWrite`). Once the render is done, I want the `openDirectoryAfterRender` function to be called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you bit confused about the callback. You should call DataWrite from another function or outside itself. Here is a updated version of your code and tested in nuke and it works

```
import nuke
import subprocess

# Create DateWrite function
def DateWrite():

    # Create Variables
    selectedNodes = nuke.selectedNodes() # Get Selection of all selected nodes

    if len(selectedNodes) == 1:
        filePath = nuke.getFilename('Set Output Directory') # Asks the user to set an OutPut directory for the Write Node

        writeNode = nuke.createNode("Write") # Create a Write Node
        writeNode['file'].setValue(filePath + "[file rootname [file tail [value root.name]]]_[date %y][date %m][date %d]_[date %H][date %M].png") # Set the Write Node with TCL
        writeNode['afterRender'].setValue('openDirectoryAfterRender(%s)' % filePath) # Add a callback which will call the function openDirectoryAfterRender()

    else:
        nuke.message("No node selected or more than one node are selected.\nPlease select only one node.")

# Create openDirectoryAfterRender
def openDirectoryAfterRender(directoryToOpen):
    directoryToOpen = directoryToOpen.replace('/','\\') # Replace the slashes with backslashes

    subprocess.Popen('explorer %s' % directoryToOpen) # Open the chosen directory

directoryToOpen = DateWrite() # Get the returned directory from DateWrite() -but also execute DateWrite another time-
```